# "data argument not used by format string" error for mario, cs50

Tags: c, string, format, cs50

I can't finish my Mario code (making a step) for cs50. Does anyone tell me what needs to be added here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
    n = get_int("Height: ");// height determines how may steps are to be made
    }
    while (n < 1 || n > 8); 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
      {
      printf(" ", n - 1 - i);
      printf("#", i + 1);
      printf("\n");
    }

}
```

error says this and I can't figure out how to solve this.

```
marioblock.c:16:19: error: data argument not used by format string [-Werror,-Wformat-extra-args]
      printf(" ", n - 1 - i);
             ~~~  ^
marioblock.c:17:19: error: data argument not used by format string [-Werror,-Wformat-extra-args]
      printf("#", i + 1);
             ~~~  ^
marioblock.c:21:2: error: expected '}'
}
 ^
marioblock.c:5:1: note: to match this '{'
{
```

Comment: without `%` in the format the args are useless, and cannot be used (the format indicates how to extract values from varargs)

Comment: In your first two calls to `printf`, you have a second argument but no corresponding conversion specifier in the format string. Add, for example, a `%d` to that string, to print the integer.

Comment: ooooh, I see. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

The `printf` function accepts as its first argument a format string. That is, in order to include the subsequent arguments in the output string, you have to specify what types they are and where do you want them to occur, for instance

```
printf("#%d", 5); // prints "#5"
printf(" %d", 5); // prints " 5"
```

You use `%d` for integers, for other data refer to [the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).